# How do I convert a list of strings to a list of ints inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, int

So I'm writing in data from a CSV file into Python so I can do some math with it. The data in the CSV file is mock student grades; so a student's name, and then 5 test scores. I'm using the following code to put all the data into a dictionary:

```
csvfile = open('Lab03-testdata.csv', newline='')
linesreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

testScores = {}

for l in linesreader:
    testScores[l[0]] = l[1:]
```

This works, but each key has a corresponding list of *strings* not ints. My output looks something like:

```
'John Doe': ['100', '55', '34', '22', '99']
```

In order to do any math, I've been having to use a for loop to add the test scores I want into separate lists, and convert the scores into ints as I do that. However I want all the data in the dictionary to already be ints. I'm wanting something more like this:

```
'John Doe': [100, 55, 34, 22, 99]
```

So how can I convert the list of values into integers?

Comment: `list(map(int, l[1:]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `int(...)` cast to this code:

```
for l in linesreader:
    testScores[l[0]] = l[1:]
```

Notice the change within the for loop:

```
for l in linesreader:
    testScores[l[0]] = [int(i) for i in l[1:]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this functionally using a single line for loop to convert each test score in the row to an int before adding it into the list?

Comment: That's exactly what it does. It's called a list-comprehension. `list(map(int, l[1:]))` does pretty much  the same thing

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert from str to int your data

```
for l in linesreader:
    testScores[l[0]] = list(map(int, l[1:]))
```